# IdentityServer 3 and ASP.NET Identity: how to get user information

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identityserver3

I'm using IdentityServer 3 with ASP.NET Identity as its user store. I have followed this [article](https://mindfulsoftware.com.au/guidance/oauth2-walkthrough-using-identity-server-and-aspnet/creating-an-identity-server-using-aspnet-identity-and-entity-framework-storage) to set up IdentityServer and my client is an ASP MVC web application. I'm able to login from my client, but I don't understand how to get user information on the client side. On the server side Im using:

```
 var scopes = new Scope[]
            {
                StandardScopes.OpenId,
                StandardScopes.Email,
                new Scope
                {
                    Name = "roles",
                    Claims = new List<ScopeClaim>
                    {
                        new ScopeClaim("role")
                    }
                }

            };

            var clients = new Client[] 
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "mvc-demo",
                    ClientName = "MVC Demo Client",
                    Flow = Flows.Implicit,
                    RedirectUris = new List<string>
                    {
                        "http://localhost:16652/"
                    },
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        "openid", "email", "roles"
                    }
                }
            };

            var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory().Configure(connectionString);
            factory.UseInMemoryClients(clients);
            factory.UseInMemoryScopes(scopes);
```

And on the client side:

```
 app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "oidc",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "cookies",
                Authority = "https://localhost:44305/",
                ClientId = "mvc-demo",
                RedirectUri = "http://localhost:16652/",
                ResponseType = "id_token token",
                Scope = "openid email roles",

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
                    {
                        var id = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

                        var email = id.FindFirst(Constants.ClaimTypes.Email);
                        var roles = id.FindAll(Constants.ClaimTypes.Role);

                        // create new identity and set name and role claim type
                        var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(
                            id.AuthenticationType,
                            Constants.ClaimTypes.Email,
                            Constants.ClaimTypes.Role);

                        nid.AddClaim(email);
                        nid.AddClaims(roles);

                        // add some other app specific claim
                        //nid.AddClaim(new Claim("app_specific", "some data"));

                        n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                            nid,
                            n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
```

But I cant get the information about users email for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to send claims to my client application this way:

```
var scopes = new Scope[]
            {
                StandardScopes.OpenId,
                new Scope
                {
                    Name = "roles",
                    Type = ScopeType.Identity,
                    Claims = new List<ScopeClaim>
                    {
                        new ScopeClaim("role")
                    }
                },
                new Scope
                {
                    Name = "email",
                    Type = ScopeType.Identity,
                    Claims = new List<ScopeClaim>
                    {
                        new ScopeClaim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Email)
                    }
                }

            };

            var clients = new Client[] 
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "mvc-demo",
                    ClientName = "MVC Demo Client",
                    Flow = Flows.Implicit,
                    RedirectUris = new List<string>
                    {
                        "http://localhost:16652/"
                    },
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        "openid", "email", "roles"
                    }
                }
            };
```

And on the client side, I needed to turn off claims transformation, to fetch them correctly, like this(in OWIN startup class):

```
AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = Constants.ClaimTypes.Subject;
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```